# How to merge large hourly rainfall data

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have 10 stations with 15 years of hourly rainfall data. All have some hours, even days jump in their series randomly. I want all the hourly time step for the 15 year duration are used as indices and then combine all the station data to one data frame, while giving NA ( or even average of some neighbours)  to the jump of each stations. so any suggestions to do this in **R**?

For instance I have data frame rainfall_1

```
date                       station210
1994-01-01 00:00:00 0
1994-01-01 02:00:00 0
1994-01-01 03:00:00 0
1994-01-01 04:00:00 0.6
1994-01-01 06:00:00 2.6
1994-01-01 07:00:00 3.2
```

and the second station is rainfall_2

```
date                      station212
1994-01-01 00:00:00 0
1994-01-01 01:00:00 1.8
1994-01-01 02:00:00 1.8
1994-01-01 03:00:00 1.8
1994-01-01 04:00:00 1.4
1994-01-01 06:00:00 1.8
```

when I try to

```
merge(rainfall_1, rainfall_2, all=TRUE)
date               station_210  station_212
1994-01-01 00:00:00 0.0 0.0
1994-01-01 02:00:00 0.0 1.8
1994-01-01 03:00:00 0.0 1.8
1994-01-01 04:00:00 0.6 1.4
1994-01-01 06:00:00 2.6 1.8
```

some of the problems are  it does miss the 2nd row of the second data frame(rainfall_2) and it miss the value at the 5th hour which is not present in both data frame. I was looking a solution where for the second time step (2 hour) to be included and to be NA or average of its neighbour and for the 5th hour time step to give the NA or average value of the neighbours for both.

Imagine if you have these time series data is for a thousands for many stations with some missing at random intervals .

Comment: Please help us help you by providing us with a reproducible example (i.e. code and example data), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for details.

Comment: Just to emphasize the need, R's time handling functions are ... let's say,  different. Really, really need to see the data. Experience has shown that new users of SO rarely provide such data after polite requests, so am voting to close. But please show that I am wroong and edit you questions to prevent closure.

Comment: It would be easier for responders if you also show the output from `dput(rainfall_1)` and `dput(rainfall_2)` .

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do what you want.  I am not sure why the final merged dataset begins at 3:00PM on Dec 31 instead of midnight Jan 1st.  I suspect that has something to do with my computer's clock relative to GMT.

```
df.1 <- read.table(text = '
date       time     station210
1994-01-01 00:00:00 0
1994-01-01 02:00:00 0
1994-01-01 03:00:00 0
1994-01-01 04:00:00 0.6
1994-01-01 06:00:00 2.6
1994-01-01 07:00:00 3.2
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df.2 <- read.table(text = '
 date       time    station212
1994-01-01 00:00:00 0
1994-01-01 01:00:00 1.8
1994-01-01 02:00:00 1.8
1994-01-01 03:00:00 1.8
1994-01-01 04:00:00 1.4
1994-01-01 06:00:00 1.8
', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

cols <- c( 'date' , 'time' )

df.1$datetime <- apply( df.1[ , cols ] , 1 , paste , collapse = " " )
df.2$datetime <- apply( df.2[ , cols ] , 1 , paste , collapse = " " )

df.1 <- df.1[, c('datetime', 'station210')]
df.2 <- df.2[, c('datetime', 'station212')]

df.3 <- merge(df.1, df.2, by="datetime", all=TRUE)

df.3[order(df.3$datetime),]

df.3$datetime <- format(as.POSIXct(df.3$datetime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),  "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" )
df.3

hour <- seq(0,60*60*24,by=60*60)

datetime <- as.POSIXlt(hour, origin="1994-01-01")

datetime <-  format( as.POSIXct(hour, origin="1994-01-01"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"  )

newdf <- merge(data.frame(datetime), df.3, all.x=TRUE, by="datetime")
newdf

              datetime station210 station212
1  1993-12-31 15:00:00         NA         NA
2  1993-12-31 16:00:00         NA         NA
3  1993-12-31 17:00:00         NA         NA
4  1993-12-31 18:00:00         NA         NA
5  1993-12-31 19:00:00         NA         NA
6  1993-12-31 20:00:00         NA         NA
7  1993-12-31 21:00:00         NA         NA
8  1993-12-31 22:00:00         NA         NA
9  1993-12-31 23:00:00         NA         NA
10 1994-01-01 00:00:00        0.0        0.0
11 1994-01-01 01:00:00         NA        1.8
12 1994-01-01 02:00:00        0.0        1.8
13 1994-01-01 03:00:00        0.0        1.8
14 1994-01-01 04:00:00        0.6        1.4
15 1994-01-01 05:00:00         NA         NA
16 1994-01-01 06:00:00        2.6        1.8
17 1994-01-01 07:00:00        3.2         NA
18 1994-01-01 08:00:00         NA         NA
19 1994-01-01 09:00:00         NA         NA
20 1994-01-01 10:00:00         NA         NA
21 1994-01-01 11:00:00         NA         NA
22 1994-01-01 12:00:00         NA         NA
23 1994-01-01 13:00:00         NA         NA
24 1994-01-01 14:00:00         NA         NA
25 1994-01-01 15:00:00         NA         NA
```

EDIT - July 6, 2013

Here is one way to handle more than two data frames.

Here are the data:

```
df.1 <- read.table(text = '
date       time     station210
1994-01-01 00:00:00 0
1994-01-01 02:00:00 0
1994-01-01 03:00:00 0
1994-01-01 04:00:00 0.6
1994-01-01 06:00:00 2.6
1994-01-01 07:00:00 3.2
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df.2 <- read.table(text = '
 date       time    station212
1994-01-01 00:00:00 0
1994-01-01 01:00:00 1.8
1994-01-01 02:00:00 1.8
1994-01-01 03:00:00 1.8
1994-01-01 04:00:00 1.4
1994-01-01 06:00:00 1.8
', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df.3 <- read.table(text = '
 date       time    station214
1993-12-31 22:00:00 5.0
1993-12-31 23:00:00 2.0
1994-01-01 02:00:00 1.0
1994-01-01 04:00:00 3.0
1994-01-01 06:00:00 5.0
1994-01-01 08:00:00 4.0
', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Create a list of data frames and create the variable `datetime`:

```
my.data <- sapply(paste('df.', seq(1,3,1), sep=''), get, environment(), simplify = FALSE) 

date.time <- function(x) { 
                      cols <- c( 'date' , 'time' )
                      x$datetime <- apply( x[ , cols ] , 1 , paste , collapse = " " )
                      x <- x[, 3:4]
                      return(x)
             }

my.list <- lapply(my.data, function(x) date.time(x))
```

Merge and sort the data frames in that list:

```
df.3 <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), my.list)
df.3[order(df.3$datetime),]
```

Add missing dates and times to the merged data frame:

```
df.3$datetime <- format(as.POSIXct(df.3$datetime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),  "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" )

hour <- seq(0,60*60*24,by=60*60)

datetime <- as.POSIXlt(hour, origin="1994-01-01")

datetime <-  format( as.POSIXct(hour, origin="1994-01-01"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"  )

newdf <- merge(data.frame(datetime), df.3, all.x=TRUE, by="datetime")
newdf
```

Here is code to replace missing observations from a station with the mean of the preceding and following observations from that same station.  I am using nested `for-loops` which are likely highly inefficient.  If I figure out a more efficient approach I will try to remember to post it here.  If your data set is huge, these nested `for-loops` may take a very long time to run.

```
newdf2 <- newdf

for(i in 1:nrow(newdf)) {
     for(j in 2:ncol(newdf)) {

          if(i == 1 &                   is.na(newdf[i,j]))  newdf2[i,j] = newdf[i+1,j]
          if(i ==         nrow(newdf) & is.na(newdf[i,j]))  newdf2[i,j] = newdf[i-1,j]
          if(i >  1 & i < nrow(newdf) & is.na(newdf[i,j]))  newdf2[i,j] = mean(c(newdf[i-1,j], newdf[i+1,j]), na.rm=TRUE) 
          if(is.nan(newdf2[i,j]))                           newdf2[i,j] = NA

     }
}

cbind(newdf, newdf2)
```

Comment: Hi Mark Miller, thank you and that is working for me. But there is one question, is there a way we can have some average of the previous and the next time series value in place of NA?

Comment: Hi Mark Miller, when i do it for more than two station, i am getting error message "Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 
  'by' must specify column(s) as numbers, names or logical" . what do you suggest me to solve this problem ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Wuletawu Abera I now have tried to respond to your questions above.

Answer (score 0):

Assume `rainfall_1` and `rainfall_2` have POSIXct `date` columns.  Now, convert the data frames to zoo objects and add a third zoo object `z3` (equal to `z2`) to the example just to show its not limited to two inputs.  Merge all three (zoo's merge handles multiway merges) to give `zz` and then merge the combined time series with a zero width grid, `z0`.

```
library(zoo)

# set up input zoo objects
z1 <- read.zoo(rainfall_1, FUN = identity)
z2 <- read.zoo(rainfall_2, FUN = identity)
z3 <- z2

zz <- merge(z1, z2, z3)
z0 <- zoo(, seq(start(zz), end(zz), by = "hour"))
zout <- merge(zz, z0)
```

This gives:

```
> zout
                     z1  z2  z3
1994-01-01 00:00:00 0.0 0.0 0.0
1994-01-01 01:00:00  NA 1.8 1.8
1994-01-01 02:00:00 0.0 1.8 1.8
1994-01-01 03:00:00 0.0 1.8 1.8
1994-01-01 04:00:00 0.6 1.4 1.4
1994-01-01 05:00:00  NA  NA  NA
1994-01-01 06:00:00 2.6 1.8 1.8
1994-01-01 07:00:00 3.2  NA  NA
```

You may wish to just leave this in zoo to take advantage of its other facilities too but if you do want to turn it back into a data frame:

```
library(ggplot2)
dfout <- fortify(zout)
```